# How to send Multiple values in GET request using CSV in Serenity BDD framework

Tags: java, csv, rest-assured, serenity-bdd, path-parameter

How to pass CSV with multiple values in GET Request.
When I am tried to pass the values as below its not giving the response properly.please help here to get the response.

For Eg: My CSV file contains ID's: 15,16,20

How can I pass this ID's in GET request.

**EmployeeID.csv**

```
EmployeeID
15
16
20
```

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void init() {

        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1";
    }
    @Test
    public void getAllRequests() {
        ArrayList<String> employeeIDs = new ArrayList<>();
        employeeIDs.add(employeeID);
        SerenityRest.given().log().all().when().get("/employees/employeeID").then().log().all().statusCode(200);
        System.out.println(employeeID);
    }
}
```

Comment: which serenity's version you are working on?

Comment: <serenity.version>2.4.51

Comment: This serenity version uses JUnit4, then you can follow this tutorial to do data-driven testing https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/junit-data-driven.html

Comment: Hi,
I followed your code and used it.

My CSV has 3 different Customer ID's.
I used your code and see that it ran for 3 times because I have 3 different Customer ID's.

But I see that that my customer ID's are not getting populated in this code of line -

SerenityRest.given().log().all().when().get("/employees/employeeID").then().log().all().statusCode(200);

I am writing my code like this -

Comment: is this correct ? 

@Test
 public void getAllRequests() {
  ArrayList<String> employeeIDs = new ArrayList<>();
  employeeIDs.add(employeeID);
  
  SerenityRest.given().log().all().when().get("/employees/15").then().log().all().statusCode(200);
  System.out.println(employeeID);
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would work for you

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityParameterizedRunner;
import net.serenitybdd.rest.SerenityRest;
import net.thucydides.junit.annotations.UseTestDataFrom;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(SerenityParameterizedRunner.class)
@UseTestDataFrom(value = "EmployeeID.csv")
public class DemoTest {

    private int EmployeeID;

    public void setEmployeeID(int EmployeeID) {
        this.EmployeeID = EmployeeID;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1";
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllRequests() {
        SerenityRest.given().log().all().when()
                .get("/employees/" + EmployeeID)
                .then().log().all()
                .statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

File csv at: `src/test/resources/EmployeeID.csv`

Comment: @LeaningVin Please mark it as correct answer. Don't just comment.